# Installing new symfony project

Tags: symfony

[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
  Failed to create "/var/www/html/.143986856455d2a694104cb": mkdir(): Permiss
  ion denied.

I tried to execute new symfony project, how can I handle this?

Comment: can you provide more information like what operating system are you installing it on

Answer (score 0):

Set permissions on app/logs and app/cache folders:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*

$ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo chmod +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't the permission to write in the file or the folder.

For create a new project of symfony you need to do this.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

after that you downloading composer and symfony by this command

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and

```
sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

you edit the permission of symfony.

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

and create the project
    symfony new NameOfTheProject
like simple user not in root or using sudo.

you can also download the demo like that

```
symfony demo
```

i advise you to do this without the "[" , "]"

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/[NameProjectHere]
```

;)